# asp.net MVC Save submit not populating Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am submitting a form which is held in a partial view, in the controller I want to send it to the Display Partial View which route would be /item/display/idvalue but the page renders what appears to be the partial view as the entire page but has the route of item/save

My controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(ItemDetail model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var itemLogicModel = new ItemLogicModel()
            {
                Id = model.Id,
                ChecklistItem = model.Description,
                DefaultOn = model.DefaultOn,
                FieldItem = model.FieldItem,
                ImageName = model.ImageName,
                IsSystem = model.IsSystem
            };
            mItemService.SaveItem(itemLogicModel, Enumerations.RecordSaveType.SaveAndClose);

        }
        return PartialView("Display", model);
    }
```

My Partial view

```
@using PresentationLayer.Areas.Resource.Models
@model ItemDetail
<script type="text/javascript">
invalidSubmit = false;
</script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "Item", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "ViewEditPartial" }, new { id = "DetailScreen" }))
{
<div id="detail"></div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="container-head-left"></td>
        <td class="container-head-middle"></td>
        <td class="container-head-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="container-body">
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id, new {id = "ItemIdDisplayed"})

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (@Model.ToolbarSettings.IsEditMode)
                        {
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new {disabled = "disabled"})
                        }

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsSystem)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (@Model.ToolbarSettings.IsEditMode)
                        {
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSystem)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsSystem, new {disabled = "disabled"})
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DefaultOn)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (@Model.ToolbarSettings.IsEditMode)
                        {
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DefaultOn)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.DefaultOn, new {disabled = "disabled"})
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FieldItem)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (@Model.ToolbarSettings.IsEditMode)
                        {
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.FieldItem)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.FieldItem, new {disabled = "disabled"})
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @if (@Model.ToolbarSettings.IsEditMode)
                        {
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageName, new {@readonly = "readonly", @class = "input-disabled"})
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ImageName, new {disabled = "disabled"})
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Image Preview</td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="@Model.ImagePath@Model.ImageName-red.png" alt="Red Image" />
                        <img src="@Model.ImagePath@Model.ImageName-amber.png" alt="Amber Image" />
                        <img src="@Model.ImagePath@Model.ImageName-green.png" alt="Green Image" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    }
    <script type="text/html" id="editButtonLink">
    <a href="#" onclick="loadEdit('@Model.Id');">Edit</a>
</script>

<script
 type="text/html" id="cancelButtonLink">
     <a href="#" onclick="loadCancel('@Model.Id');">Cancel</a>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="saveButtonLink">
     <a href="#" onclick="loadSave();">Save</a>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadCancel(id) {
        $("#ViewEditPartial").load("@Url.Action("CancelEdit", "Item")", { 'id': id },
            function (response, status, xhr) {
            });
    }

    function loadEdit(id) {
        $("#ViewEditPartial").load("@Url.Action("Edit", "Item")", { 'id': id },
             function (response, status, xhr) {
             });
    }

    function loadSave() {
        document.forms["DetailScreen"].submit();
    }


    var viewModelToolbar =
    {
        newButtonClass: '@Model.ToolbarSettings.NewButtonClass',
        newActionClass: '@Model.ToolbarSettings.NewButtonAction',
        editButtonClass: '@Model.ToolbarSettings.EditButtonClass',
        saveButtonClass: '@Model.ToolbarSettings.SaveButtonClass',
        deleteButtonClass: '@Model.ToolbarSettings.DeleteButtonClass',
        cancelButtonClass: '@Model.ToolbarSettings.CancelButtonClass',
        idValue: { value: '@Model.Id' },
        };
    ko.cleanNode(document.body);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModelToolbar);

</script>
```

On the Main View is the save button that is actually clicked with the template being re-rendered on the initial load of the display Partial View

```
<div id="SaveButton" data-bind="css: saveButtonClass">
      <div data-bind="template: {name:'saveButtonLink'}"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the Save to render into the ViewEditPartial, but it is loading as a View instead, I can't see what I am doing wrong

edit::

In my layout

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @RenderSection("script", required: false)
</head>
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated, I have tried all the suggestions and none of them are working.

Comment: Your using an ajax post...Is this on purpose? Try swapping with @Html.BeginForm...This perform a sync post to your controller and return your partial view Display.

Comment: To be fair I inherited the code from 2 people who had 'had a go' and I'm new to MVC .net style myself, I shall give that a go.

Comment: how do I tell @Html.Beginform the Div id?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem is that you aren't referencing these file in your `view` or `Layout`:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`jQuery` is required as well of course :)

Comment: The Ajax, works as I am referencing them in my Layout Page, but found it hard to include all the relevant code without including loads of irrelevant code.

Comment: Are you sure it works? Can you watch the Console while submitting?

Comment: I get to my Save method on my controller, it isn't until it comes back it gets lost.

Comment: in my layout      <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @RenderSection("script", required: false)
</head>

Comment: Yes you are getting to the Save method, but you are getting in a non AJAX way.

Comment: OK, cool thanks, just updated my post to show the included js in my layout which includes the file you mentioned, my single display method which displays a single item in the partial view that is then saved works OK, so I believe all the elements for an ajax post are there, so what could I be missing when saving?  Which console window do you mean? in f12 debug tools?

Comment: I do apologize I have no idea what I am looking for the console window gave me this DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
File: Index
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
File: Save
HTML1527: DOCTYPE expected. Consider adding a valid HTML5 doctype: "<!DOCTYPE html>".
File: Save, Line: 1, Column: 1
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
File: Index

Comment: OK, so it is navigating away, but I'm still at a complete loss as to why it might be doing this, all my js files are in the right place (I believe) and other partial views into the same div that aren't submits work fine, is there a difference between an href and a submit when it comes to partial views?